# Symfony2 form dynamic select entity

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, dynamic

I searched for a while, but i didn't find anything.

I want to create a dynamic select with another select. Example :

in my form i have two field (category & subcategory) linked to an entity, when i select an item in category drop-down the item in subcategory will change.

So ok i found i can manage with a event listener.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        var_dump($data->getCategory());
    });
```

Ok, i can get the selected category and after load the subcategory, but how i can call this with ajax ?

Hope you have any example...

Answer (score 0):

The response is not so simple... Basically, if you want to build a form according to initial & submitted value, you need to attach an event listener to the PRE_SET_DATA & PRE_SUBMIT event. When the form is initialized, the PRE_SET_DATA event is fired. Here, you will receive your object as data in the form event or null if you don't provide one (Don't forget to handle this case). With this first part, you will be able to build your form dynamically according to your initial data.

Then, when you will handle your form, the PRE_SUBMIT event will be fired if the form is submitted. In this event, you will reveive a flat array wilt all the submitted datas. According to this array, you can rebuild your form according to the submitted datas. The main issue here is the array is an array & not your model object. Meaning you will not have a category object but his view representation (his ID)...

Hope it helps!